# Read all the datas setted in my object

Tags: android

I would like to read all the responses I have set in my object.

This is my object :

```
public class Reponses {

    private String id;
    private String reponse;

    public Reponses(String id, String reponse) {
        this.id = id;
        this.reponse = reponse;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getReponse() {
        return reponse;
    }

    public void setReponse(String reponse) {
        this.reponse = reponse;
    }
}
```

This is where I set the object :

```
Reponses reponses[] = {
                                new Reponses("1", "AB"),
                                new Reponses("2", "D"),
                                new Reponses("3", "ABC"),
                                new Reponses("4", "B"),
                                new Reponses("5", "AC")
                        };

                        Log.d("debug", "reponses : " + reponses);
```

In my Log I have :

```
02-20 15:29:31.252 /code D/debug: reponses : [Lcode.models.Reponses;@6f85c97
```

Why I don't have all the strings I have set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just displaying the reference of your array so

use [`Arrays.toString(reponses)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])) and `override` `toString()` function in your `Reponses` class

e.g

```
 class Reponses {
   // .. code

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id+":"+reponse;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
Log.d("debug", "reponses : " + Arrays.toString(reponses));
```